# Simulate long running queries in Elasticsearch. Aka sleep or delay commands

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I see that timeouts in Elasticsearch could be query or network-client related.
I would like to emulate behavior of a long running query to see what will happen.
Something like the `sleep` or `delay` commands that are missing in Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on 7th version of Elasticsearch.

- You need an index that has minimum one document.
  (Or use a system index, but in a future major version, direct access to system indices will be prevented by default)
- Or your query should return at least one doc.

**Precaution 1** This timeout measures in "parrots", ha-ha.
See `parrotTimeout` variable. It increases the real time delay in a progression. So, 5 000 parrots could work well for you but 10 000 could hung your Elasticsearch installation up till a restart.

**Precaution 2** Elasticsearch survives about 8 minutes before a crash with this approach in Macbook Pro with running inside a Docker container.

**BTW**, you could use this approach to test long running Elasticsearch tasks with
`?wait_for_completion=false`, too.

Use the following code.

```
GET /events/_search
{
  "timeout": "5m",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": """
              // This heuristic timeout could only be <= 999999
              def parrotTimeout = 4000;
              
              def map1 = new HashMap();
              def map2 = new HashMap();
              
              for (int i = 0; i < parrotTimeout; ++i) {
                def key = i.toString();
                def val = new Random().nextInt(1000000000).toString();
                def noneExistingVal = "oppa la-la";
                
                map1.put(key, val);
                map1.containsValue(noneExistingVal);
                map2.put(key, val);
                map2.containsValue(noneExistingVal);
              }
            """
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  } 
}
```

You could prevent "execution caching" and query time decreasing in Elasticsearch if you'll update some random string in your script.
In case of the Nest lib and C# this will be like the following. See `Guid.NewGuid()` below.

```
var res = _client.Client.Search<T>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Script(s => s
            .Script(ss => ss
                .Source($@"
def parrotTimeout = 4000;

def map1 = new HashMap();

for (int i = 0; i < parrotTimeout; ++i) {{
  def key = i.toString();
  def val = new Random().nextInt(1000000000).toString();
  def noneExistingVal = ""oppa {Guid.NewGuid()}"";

  map1.put(key, val);
  map1.containsValue(noneExistingVal);
}}
")
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Also it works with the "update" or "update by query" Elasticsearch queries. Some C# example is below.

```
$@"ctx._source.{targetFieldName}=ctx._source.{sourceFiledName}; ctx._source.remove('{sourceFiledName}');

def parrotTimeout = 4000;

def map1 = new HashMap();

for (int i = 0; i < parrotTimeout; ++i) {{
  def key = i.toString();
  def val = new Random().nextInt(1000000000).toString();
  def noneExistingVal = ""oppa {Guid.NewGuid()}"";
  
  map1.put(key, val);
  map1.containsValue(noneExistingVal);
}}
"
```