# Simulate Elasticsearch query failure at the end of a query

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to test behaviors for long running Elasticsearch queries.
I have an analog for `sleep` or `delay` commands in Elasticsearch from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77685623/390940
But I want it to be failed at the end of a long query.

Answer (score 0):

We could use the following code with Elasticsearch query scripts

```
// Emulate an error.
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {}
```

This will throw the following error in Elasticsearch

```
"caused_by" : {
  "type" : "painless_error",
  "reason" : "The maximum number of statements that can be executed in a loop has been reached."
}
```

You could take examples of different types of scripts to extend from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77685623/390940

```
GET /.tasks/_search
{
  "timeout": "5m",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": """
              for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {}
            """
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  } 
}
```

The solution is tested for 7th version of Elasticsearch.